# Why Does my Ajax Not work on Google Chrome Or IE but works on FireFox, And how can i make it work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

/* ajax not working on Chrome or IE*/
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
function pg2() {
    request.open("GET","Html/picture.html",true);

    request.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Are you testing it locally or is it being run off a server?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `new XMLHttpRequest();.`

Comment: yes i noticed the syntax error by  new XMLHttpRequest();. the dot shouldn't be there.

Comment: i'm testing it locally the web page in total work perfect but only on Firefox when i try use it on EI or Google Chrome The Ajax Doesn't Work

Comment: Where and how do you call `pg()`

Comment: pg() is the functions name, it stands for page in this case pg2() means page two ok i am using a menu on the web page when the user clicks on a link named picture (<a>picture</a>) the id named content will change inside the "<a>" i got an event handler called Onclick, the piece of code looks as follows



<a onClick="javascript:pg2()" href="#" >hair pieces</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just opening your http page directly from your HD, I believe you're getting a network error related to cross domain origin. Chrome enforces that AJAX requests have to go to the same origin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

It should work if you use an HTTP server such as Apache or IIS to serve your page.

You can open the developer tools by right clicking on the page and then selecting Inspect Element to see what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line has a syntax error (the trailing period).

Different browsers use different JavaScript engines and it may be that Firefox's is more lenient.

Fix your JS and you should be good to go.

Comment: i fixed the JS and i Still Got the problem but thank you for helping

Comment: Please update the question if you still need assistance or mark the question as answered. Thanks.